# How do you make an input element fill parent?

Tags: html, css

I've got the following html:

```
<div class="container">
    <form>
        <input class="search" type="text" />
        <button class="submit" type="submit">Go</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

I'm trying to make the text input fill to the size of the container, minus the width of the Go button that will be inline on the right. However, I can't seem to get the input to fill the width of the container. I've got the following css (simplified):

```
.container {
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}

.search {
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    right: 40px;
}

.submit {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    width: 40px;
}
```

Producing the following design:

[image]

How do I actually get that inner text box to fill the width of the parent? Without using %, since I need it to stretch right up to the button and no further.

Comment: add `width: calc(100% - 40px)` in search class...voila!! :)

Comment: Using the calc function would involve dropping some older browsers support, so I would prefer a more supported answer if it exists, even if it's a little more complicated.

Comment: Use javascript/jquery to make the calculation for you.

Comment: if you want to do it without calc, you can estimate %... here is my example - i hope it helps you: http://jsfiddle.net/ItayB/upp2L/

Comment: @ItayB Nice simple and clean solution. But the submit button grows with the size of the screen, not sure if that is wanted.

Comment: There's really no way to do this with plain CSS? Why does using

    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: auto;

work for everything but the input?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how to do it with cross-browser css:

I wrapped the input in an extra div:

```
<div class="container">
    <form>
        <div class="search-padder">
            <input class="search" type="text" />
        </div>
        <button class="submit" type="submit">Go</button>
    </form>
</div>



.container {
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}

.search-padder {
    padding-right: 40px;
    width: 100%;
}

.search {
    width: 100%;
}

.submit {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 40px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

unless you use javascript or `calc`, input box is going to overlap underneath the button because its set in `px` and `input` in percentage!

```
.search {
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    right: 60px;
    width:90%; /* this is the deal here*/
}
```

[**to get you started**](http://jsfiddle.net/UK4YX/1/)

Answer (score 0):

For mozzila add following css in `.search`

```
width: -moz-available;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would just go with Jquery.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var inputWidth = $('.container').width() - $('.submit').width();
    $('input').css('width', inputWidth);        
});
```

Comment: question is not tagged in jquery...thats why i avoided the js solution!! :)

Comment: Thsts ok. It is the most clean and elegant way with the most control. Why avoid js when it is so powerful?

Comment: even i agree with jquery...but we dont know for sure what OP's requirements are...otherwise JQ is always the first option!! ;)

Comment: That is true, but although he did not put the tag there that does not mean he wants just a CSS/HTML solution. He might not even be aware of JS or javascript. Imho, if you do not want certain types of of answer then the OP should specify that within the question. I cannot find any reason to not use Jquery other then JS/JQuery being unkown to OP.

Comment: I was hoping for a compatible CSS solution, I always try to keep my JS separate from design. This is a good solution, but I would prefer one with as compatible of CSS as possible.

Comment: Actually, the input isn't going to automatically resize of the width of the browser window changes..

Comment: @Chaseph That was not the question. The question was how to fill a input box in a parent.